# In VSTS Duplicate Feature or Epic with Work Items

Tags: azure-devops

We have a project that often has the exact same work flow needed.
We have a feature that includes detailed work items, along with very helpful descriptions.

Is there not a way to take a current Feature and duplicate it along with all of the work items?
I have tried using templates but that has not worked out.
I tried Copy Work Item and checked 'Include existing links' but it does not copy the Related Work, which is what I need.

To further clarify I would like to duplicate a Feature, along with its Product Backlog Items and their Tasks.

Comment: If this should be moved someplace else please feel free to tell me.
If it is a duplicate tell me that.
This is a important part of our workflow and a serious question that impacts our team.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Voting just to close it without offering some guidance on why is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to use powershell and VSTS REST API to achieve this copying. A sample powershell is available in the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589446/how-to-copy-a-work-item-and-its-tasks)

You can modify that and create a script to support your needs.

Comment: That looks like that will do it.  Thank you.  It would be a pretty useful addition to VSTS I think.